# get a codebehind value in javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net-2010

I want to get a codebehind value in my javascript function. My scenario is, Lets say I have two Usercontrols A and B.
I am setting a global value from UserControl A. When I come to UserControl B's page load, I am accessing that value and putting it into a hidden field. 
I have a button on UserControl B which calls a javascript function on client click.
On that function I am trying to catch the hiddenfields current value. But I always get 0 from the hidden field value. What I am doing wrong? Can someone help me?

Below is the code:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="DetailsForm.ascx.vb" Inherits="TD_Web_App.DetailsForm" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetNextRecord() {
    debugger;
    var currentVal = $get("DetailsFormPanel_DetailsForm1_HFDetails").value; 
//clientID of my hidden field
}
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="DetailInfoUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" > 

  <ContentTemplate>
<table id="TDPropsGrid" runat="server" width="250px" ></table>
    <asp:Button ID="Cmd_Next" runat="server" Text="Next" Width="100px" SkinID="ButtonSkin" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="GetNextRecord()"/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonDetails" runat="server" style="display:none;">
LinkButton 
</asp:LinkButton>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HFDetails" runat="server" />
```

On code behind:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    showData() 'some function
    HFDetails.Value = CurrentRecordCounter  ' global value coming from other usercontrol 
End Sub

'Private Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
'    HFDetails.Value = CurrentRecordCounter
'End Sub
```

I have tried putting

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HFDetails" runat="server" />
```

inside the update panel, nothing changed.

But at GetNextRecord() the currentVal is always "0". why?

Comment: Try var currentVal=$("#"DetailsFormPanel_DetailsForm1_HFDetails").val();

Comment: Did you check the value of that hidden field in the HTML source in the browser? As in: is it the codebehind that's not setting the value or is it the javascript that's not reading it correctly?

Comment: thanks for the help guys. sorry for being late on this. dont know how, but the same code is working on another development environment. So all is well for now. I will look into this when I will have some spare time. Thanks again for your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var currentVal = $('#<%=HFDetails.ClientID %>').val();
```